# Split a number string via matching digits values using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, frontend

How can I split a string containing only numbers via matching digit values using a regex.

For example:

```
"11222344"
```

would return

```
["11","222","3","44"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use back-reference to search for same characters next to each other.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

You can do it like this:

```js
var res = '11222344'.match(/(\d)\1*/g);

console.log(res);
```